Modeling a Multivariate Time Series with Non-Constant Intervals
The time series literature I've been exposed to usually assumes that multivariate data shares observation timestamps i.e. representing a VAR as $\mathbf z_t$ for $t \in \{1, \dots, T\}$. I'm currently working with multiple time series that do not share observation times in this way. Are there canonical ways to work with this type of multivariate data, or is it usually better to group the data by week/month/other interval to recover shared timestamps?
